# PyAudio On Android

Tags: android, python, c, apk, pyaudio

Does anyone have any experience installing libraries like this on Android along side SL4A, or maybe even packing it into an APK?

Since PyAudio uses C I am not entirely sure how this would be done, if it can be done at all.

Comment: I'm guessing probably difficult as outside Android, AudioFlinger isn't really used much at all

Answer (score 3):

PyAudio wraps on the [PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/) library.  So until PortAudio itself wraps Android's underlying audio system, PyAudio won't have a chance of working on Android.  In the meantime, there's a [ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/tickets/154) filed on PortAudio for Android support, which you can track.